# Relevant path to resources in maven archetypes

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I use `idea` maven archetype

```
src
---main 
------java
------resources
```

In my resources folder I has `spring_config.xml`
And when I run this code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring_config.xml");
```

Exception says to me that config file was not found. On my previous project everything worked just perfectly.

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring_config.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring_config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring_config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at ua.epam.spring.hometask.ui.console.SpringHometaskConsoleUI.initContext(SpringHometaskConsoleUI.java:41)
    at ua.epam.spring.hometask.ui.console.SpringHometaskConsoleUI.main(SpringHometaskConsoleUI.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring_config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 19 more
```

---

Could anyone explain me what is happening? Why one project see relevant path to resources folder and another not?

Comment: `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring_config.xml");` Notice the slash.

Comment: I anyway catch `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception

Comment: Please post the exact strack trace and your code.

Comment: @Tunaki, I added strack trace. Code is one line basically

Comment: @Tunaki, I created `resources` folder manually. It wasn't created by maven. Should I add it to some classpath?

Comment: Maven will add it to the classpath normally...

Comment: @Tunaki I resolved it by removing from `pom.xml` 
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <targetPath>../resources</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
Path `target/resources/spring_config.xml` didn't work either.
Could you explain me why it was happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide your context location like this :

```
"classpath*:spring_config.xml"
```

Maven will add the folder resources to the classpath without further action. In Eclipse it may be necessary to add it to the build path.